# Watir webdriver code for property inside a property

Tags: watir-webdriver

I have the following code, and I need to click on the contact us link and Browse the forum link. Also I need to grab the url associated with this links.

```
<ul class="default">
<li>
<a class="supportlink" href="http://customer.comcast.com/contact-us/?CMP=ILCCOMCOM165146" data-cim-behavior="external">
<b class="icon left contact"></b>
Contact Us 
<b class="ichevron">»</b>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a class="supportlink" href="http://forums.comcast.com/?CMP=ILCCOMCOM164894" data-cim-behavior="external">
<b class="icon left forum"></b>
Browse the Forums 
<b class="ichevron">»</b>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

The most straight-forward thing to do would be to locate the links by their text. However, so that you do not have to deal with the chevron in the text, I would suggest using a regex for just the text portion.

The "Contact Us" link would be accessed by:

```
browser.link(:text => /Contact Us/)
```

To click it, you would use the `click` method:

```
browser.link(:text => /Contact Us/).click
```

To get the url, you would use the `href` method:

```
browser.link(:text => /Contact Us/).href
#=> http://customer.comcast.com/contact-us/?CMP=ILCCOMCOM165146"
```

The "Browse the Forum" link would be similar:

```
browser.link(:text => /Browse the Forums/).href
browser.link(:text => /Browse the Forums/).click
```